# Create Hyperlink, add to body and then Add string beside Hyperlink

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to create a Hyperlink using Jquery with name "Dashboard" and then add label beside hyperlink with name " >> Category".

So, basically my string would be like " **Dashboard** >> Category " with dashboard underlined.

How can I do this using Jquery ?

Comment: You can start by posting the code you've already tried.

Comment: wat you want to do ?? Exactlyy

Comment: What's the `label` for? That element-type is used to associate a text-label to an `input`, `select` or `textarea` element.

Comment: I think @DavidThomas is suggesting you should use a `<span>` tag instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var link = $('<a>Dashboard</a>')
  .appendTo($('body'));


$('<label>&nbsp;&gt;&gt; Category</label>').insertAfter(link);
```

But as David Thomas points out, label is probably not the best tag to use for this. Try `<span>` instead.

```
var link = $('<a>Dashboard</a>')
  .appendTo($('body'));


$('<span>&nbsp;&gt;&gt; Category</span>').insertAfter(link);
```